# Barcode Scanner Hex output

Tags: barcode-scanner

Please help, i bought a Youjie Y600 2D barcode scanner. I use it to scan output into a textbox.

I was wondering if is there a way to confingure a handheld 2D barcode scanner to return hex/dec format output instead of a string?

Comment: No information in the user manual?

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible. Bar code scanners output strings that you can convert to any other format. One way you can do it is to listen for text-changed events on your text box and then convert the text however you wish.